# Equality of Lie groups given equality of Lie algebras

Tags: lie-groups, lie-algebras, topological-groups

I'm trying to understand the proof of Proposition I.1.9 in the book "Analysis on Symmetric Cones" by Faraut and Koranyi.

The situation is as follows. The connected compact Lie group $G_e$ and the Lie subgroup $K$ have the same associated Lie algebras. The book now claims that $G_e=K$.

What is the simplest way to understand this claim, using the least amount of Lie theory as possible?

Answer (score 1):

The subgroup-subalgebras theorem: if $G$ has Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and $\mathfrak{h}\leq \mathfrak{g}$ is a Lie subalgebra then there exists a unique connected subgroup $H\leq G$ with Lie algebra $H$. In your case, since $G_e$ is is connected it is the unique subgroup of itself with its Lie algebra.